# Jquery .css('top') returns undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Here's a quick rundown on how my app is built:

Elements are created dynamically. All the elements are draggable and resizable. I've created a function that runs when a button is clicked. Here is the function:

```
$( '#save_canvas' ).click( function(e){
      var _tmpArray = [];  //Temp Array
      var i = 0;

      $( '#canvas' ).children('.elem').each(
      //$('.elem').each(
         function(){
            _tmpArray = [];   //Temp Array
            _id = $(this).attr('id');

            _top = $( '#' + _id ).css('top');
            _left = $( '#' + _id ).css('left');
            _height = $( '#' + _id ).css('height');
            _width = $( '#' + _id ).css('width');
            _tmpArray[0]   = _id;
            _tmpArray[1]   = _height;
            _tmpArray[2]   = _width;
            _tmpArray[3]   = _top;
            _tmpArray[4]   = _left;
         }
      );
   });
```

The function works perfectly fine for **the first element (first child)**. but not the remaining ones. Here is a document.write output of the array with 3 elements created:

== LEGEND == 
Element Id 
Height 
Width 
Top 
Left

```
textblock_1
50px
150px
262px
100px

textblock_2
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined

textblock_3
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
```

I've searched far and wide online and cannot figure this one out for the life of me...help please? :)

Comment: I think the problem is coming from this _top(or anything else) = $( '#' + _id ), maybe that's the reason why they are undefined, the element is not "get" correctly, if you understand what I mean

Comment: What’s the purpose of this code anyway? And how does The corresponding HTML look like?

Comment: It's an app I am working on at the moment...it's as much as I can say for now :)

Comment: But what do you intend to do with *this* specific piece of code?

Comment: Oh! Sorry! I plan on retrieving the top, left, height, width attributes of each elements in that containing div element. Not sure if those are the details you want/need to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have IDs set on the subsequent textblocks?  You do not need to use "$( '#' + _id )" continuously, just use $(this) all the way.

Comment: Yeah I guess that  "$( '#' + _id )" really is quite redundant!

Comment: All the elements do have an ID though....as you can see from the document.write output. The IDs start with "textblock_"

Comment: @Luckner that's right. `el = $(this); _top = el.css('top');` and so on! Should be faster too

Comment: I think we're on to something here. I removed that garble and replaced it with "$(this)" and now I can get the top and left but not height and width. Probably because I am not calling those well. Thanks !! :)

Comment: _top = $( this ).css('top');
_left = $( this ).css('left');
_height = $( this ).height();
_width = $( this ).width();

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot everyone for the help in finding the issue with this piece of code!

Ends up the issue was partly because of the way I was calling the elements - I'll have to figure out why still - but also because I had to use .height() and .width():

```
_top = $( this ).css('top');
_left = $( this ).css('left');
_height = $( this ).height();
_width = $( this ).width();
```

Once again, Thanks! :)